# How does the current working draft c++ differ from the current standard

Tags: c++, standards

From searching for a PDF version of the standard I eventually came this link to the [wording draft of the C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf) from 2011. I realise I can buy a physical copy of the final standard but I'd sooner have a PDF I could easily search and refer to. What I'd like to know is, where can I find the differences list between this draft (assuming there are no other pre-ratification drafts) and the published standard? Is this draft sufficiently complete to use for casual reference?

EDIT: link updated with newer document with thanks to [R. Martinho Fernandes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46642/r-martinho-fernandes) and [Bo Persson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/597607/bo-persson).

Comment: Nice [article](http://www.softwarequalityconnection.com/2011/06/the-biggest-changes-in-c11-and-why-you-should-care/) on the changes in the new standard.

Comment: The [committee home page](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/) has a link for the [latest publicly available draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf). It is pretty close to the final draft that was approved (N3290, which was public for a while, mistakenly). There is also a repository on GitHub with [the LaTex sources](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft).

Comment: An even closer document would be [N3337.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) which is the first draft *after* the official document. The change log [N3338](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3338.html) lists all the changes made by the editor. Mostly editorials (corrected typos and earlier copy-paste-errors).

Comment: For what it's worth, the official standard is now available for $30 from the [ANSI webstore](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS/ISO/IEC%2014882-2012).